# Failed to execute package SSIS using c#

Tags: c#, ssis

I created SSIS package using integration service project in vs 2015. 
My connection establishment is successful using Datasource. I can execute package using Execute Package Utility and Command line which is successful. 
Please check below screens shots for the same. 
[image: Execute package successfully]
I am facing problem while executing same package using c#. **getting failed to execute package**. 
I have applied eventlistener, getting below error.
Please find below few screenshots for more information.
[image: Error on execute using c# code]

Code for reference:

```
Application app = new Application();
Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\Project\Sample\Package1.dtsx", listener);
DTSExecResult results = pkg.Execute(null, null, listener, null, null);
```

In results object i got failure with given error.

Comment: what basically you are doing with that "Data Flow Task"? Is the package running successfully if it runs in the BIDS?

Comment: I am new to SSIS and My requirement is fetching data from Hadoop through SSIS which i did successfully and show that data on UI / perform some operations using c#. i can preview my data using integration service project in visual studio. and can able to run also. but once dtsx file is created and i am getting given error on pkg.execute line. Actaully i dont know what is data flow task error for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tab Alleman says  you can run the package by calling a stored procedure `sp_start_job` from C# that starts SQL Agent JOB.

Here a piece of code that can be of help in this type of approach, after creating the SQL Agent JOB:

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(YOURCONNECTION);

SqlCommand ExecuteJob = new SqlCommand();
ExecuteJob.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
ExecuteJob.CommandText = "msdb.dbo.sp_start_job";
ExecuteJob.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_name", YOURJOBNAME")
ExecuteJob.Connection = Conn; 

using (Conn)
{
    Conn.Open();

    using (ExecuteJob)
    {
        ExecuteJob.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for this work around. for time being it will work. but in future i have solve this problem. if you get any solutions please let me know.
Many thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your output does not show what the exact error message is.  I have had problems in the past executing packages directly from C#.

One way around this is to create a SQL Agent job that executes the package, and then call a stored procedure from C# that starts the SQL Agent Job.